# ORACLE- Database unable to START/OPEN

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

When I'm trying to start a database (after a server patch was applied), I get the following error and I am unable to open the database.

```
SQL> startup;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 7465926656 bytes
Fixed Size                  2267744 bytes
Variable Size            1241515424 bytes
Database Buffers         6207569920 bytes
Redo Buffers               14573568 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-10458: standby database requires recovery
ORA-01196: file 1 is inconsistent due to a failed media recovery session
ORA-01110: data file 1:
'/u00/oracle/app/oracle/product/oradata/XRO/sy_XRO.dbf
```

NOTE:

```
SQL> select database_role from v$database;

DATABASE_ROLE
------------------------------------------------
PHYSICAL STANDBY

SQL> select status from v$instance;

STATUS
------------------------------------
MOUNTED
```

Comment: http://rajiboracle.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/ora-10458-standby-database-requires.html maybe

Comment: Try "recover database;". You should get a more informative error message. If not, there will be more detail in the alert log.

Comment: it shows as a standby so you can't startup. you have to issue 'startup mount' and enable recovery. Perhaps once recovery is enabled it will catch-up.

Answer (score -1):

Generally you can open standby databases as read only. Specifically you can open data guard standby databases as read only. Did you check to see if all of the data files exist? That a database is mounted, means that the control files are where they are supposed to be, not corrupted and your init/spfile is valid.

Did you patch the Oracle Home for the standby database with the same patch as the parent? Can you force database recovery on the child to get the databases in sync.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if the database needs recövery than you cant  open it .

Comment: Sure. But from the initial post I could not tell much about the state of the database. Hence, more details are needed.

Comment: I wanted to write: "I am pretty sure that the database needs recovery so you can't open it", even not in read only mode. The current (2nd) version contains the same information as the initial version. If you need more information it would make sense to ask the OP for this information in a comment to the question.